# Difficulty Filtering Nested GraphQL Fields in Shopify

Tags: graphql, shopify

Problem:
I'm facing challenges filtering results based on nested fields in a Shopify GraphQL query.

GraphQL Query:

```
{
  discountNodes(first: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        discount {
          ... on DiscountAutomaticApp {
            appDiscountType {
              app {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Issue:
The query retrieves a list of discounts, but I'm struggling to filter the results based on the title field within the nested app field.

Desired Outcome:
I want to filter discounts where the title property of the app within the appDiscountType matches a specific value, for example, "XYZ"

Questions:

1. Is it possible to perform nested field searches directly within the Shopify GraphQL query language ?
2. What are alternative approaches or best practices for achieving this type of filtering locally ?

Tried Approaches:

1. `discountNodes(first: 100,query:"appDiscountType.app.title:'XYZ'") {`
2. `discountNodes(first: 100,query:"title:'XYZ'") {`

[Shopify graphql explorer](https://shopify.dev/graphiql/admin-graphiql)

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I expected the query to retrieve discounts where the title property of the app matches a specific value, such as "XYZ" However, the query either returns empty or the data ignoring the filter.